# Error while running - npx lwc-create-app my-app

Tags: lightning-web-components

$ npx lwc-create-app my-app
npx: installed 372 in 30.586s

```
Error: Cannot find module './generators/CreateGenerator'
    at Create.run (~/.npm/_npx/3407/lib/node_modules/lwc-create-app/lib/index.js:12:30)
    at Create._run (~/.npm/_npx/3407/lib/node_modules/lwc-create-app/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/command.js:44:31)
```

Comment: would you like to mention your OS version and node version ?I was able to create an app .

Comment: OS->Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS;
Node -> 10.12.0;